# How to make equations, figures and theorems use the same numbering scheme

Tags: floats, equations, numbering, theorems

It was asked a while ago how to make equation use the same counter as a theorem for example and one solution was to make the theorem counter use the equation instead by using

```
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}
```

Now what if I also want figures to follow the same pattern? Figures use the counter figure and theorem can’t have two counters.

Comment: This is lockstep again. :-) Please split your question/answer into one question and one answer (self-answers are allowed, although one should normally wait some time to give other users a chance to answer). BTW, I have a (hopefully) better solution.

Answer (score 17):

Adding `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` before every `figure` environment is cumbersome and error-prone. Assuming you have succeeded in connecting theorem counters to the equation counter, here's how to make equations and figures share a counter (add this to your preamble):

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@figure
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The OP provided an answer to his own question as part of the question. I cut and pasted his text into a separate answer.*

After some digging I found a (not so satisfactory) solution: put this in a preamble to the document

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

and whenever you have a figure, just before the `\begin{figure}`, put the following:

```
\addtocounter{equation}{1}
```

Funny enough moving the above command (which increments the equation counter) inside the `\renewcommand` above doesn’t work! All figures will remain with the same number... :/