# Defining shared counters for theorem environments *after* environments are defined

Tags: numbering, environments, counters, sv-classes

I am trying to use the same numbering for theorems, propositions, definitions, etc. This is normally easily be solved by using `amsmath` and defining these environments and using the same counter:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]  
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
```

Problem: I am using a journal document class which has `theorem`s, `proposition`s, `definition`s, etc. already defined in the document class. Thus I need to change the counter **after** the environments were already defined, something similar to the way one can simply change the numbering format with:

```
\renewcommand{\theprop}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{prop}}
```

In my case, the document class is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
```

---

Just found the very simple solution inspired from [How to identify the counter of Equation, Theorem, and Section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41299/how-to-identify-the-counter-of-equation-theorem-and-section). The solution is to match the counters:

```
\makeatletter
\let\c@proposition\c@theorem
\let\c@corollary\c@theorem
\let\c@lemma\c@theorem
\let\c@definition\c@theorem
\let\c@example\c@theorem
\makeatother
```

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: note -- `amsmath` does *not* have anything to do with theorem counters; it's `amsthm`.  i'm writing this as a comment instead of editing the question because it's a common misconception, and this might get the point across more clearly.

Answer (score 7):

The definition of these environments in [`svjour3`](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html) are actually initiated using a "special theorem macro" that just receives a bunch of formatting (plus counter and name) information from the respective environments. Originally, `theorem`, `proposition` and `definition` are defined like this:

```
> \theorem=macro:
->\@spthm {theorem}{\csname theoremname\endcsname }{\bfseries }{\itshape }.

> \proposition=macro:
->\@spthm {proposition}{\csname propositionname\endcsname }{\bfseries }{\itshape }.

> \definition=macro:
->\@spthm {definition}{\csname definitionname\endcsname }{\bfseries }{\rmfamily }.
```

All you need to do is make the `proposition` and `definition` environment starting macros to resemble that of `theorem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}% http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html
\makeatletter
\def\proposition{\@spthm{theorem}{\csname propositionname\endcsname}{\bfseries}{\itshape}}
\def\definition{\@spthm{theorem}{\csname definitionname\endcsname}{\bfseries}{\itshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}This is a theorem.\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}This is a proposition.\end{proposition}
\begin{definition}This is a definition.\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}This is a theorem.\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}This is a proposition.\end{proposition}
\begin{definition}This is a definition.\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `svjour3` class uses a different command for defining new "theorems", but doesn't require it. If you pass the `nospthms` option, none of the predefined theorems will be defined.

```
\documentclass[nospthms]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the toolbox offered by the class, you can undefine the predefined environments:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}

% Undefine the predefined environments
\let\theorem\relax
\let\proposition\relax
\let\definition\relax

% Define them anew
\spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spnewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}{\bfseries}{\upshape}
```