# Make algorithm2e use existing counter

Tags: counters, algorithm2e

algorithm2e provides no option to use e.g. the `subsection` counter to number the algorithms. It only provides an option to create a new counter within e.g. the `section` counter. This counter will then be independent of the `subsection` counter, though.

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly the solution is to just overwrite the `algocf` counter that algorithm2e uses.

```
\makeatletter
    \let\c@algocf\c@subsection
\makeatother
```

To have the counter displayed as chapter.section.subsection I did:

```
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}
    {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{algocf}}
```

I found the answer in [Defining shared counters for theorem environments *after* environments are defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88721/defining-shared-counters-for-theorem-environments-after-environments-are-defin?rq=1)